# booklet with sections separate markers

Tags: pdftex

I am writing an exam booklet that has different sets of questions intended for grade 5 to grade 9. I use article class and each section contains a separate set of questions. I wish to put 6 big numbers 5 for pages that contain questions for grade 5, 6 big numbers 6 for pages that contains questions for grade 6, ...etc, all at top margin. Could you suggest any packages for doing this?

For example, pages that have questions for grade 5 look something like this on top margin:

[image]

Comment: what is the relationship between grades and sections or any division of doument? 6 big numbers at header? can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`eso-pic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) package to add the number at the desired location. Using a macro to hold the number and redefining it, you can get the desired result. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\Grade{5}
\newcommand\GradeHeader{%
  \fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont%
  {\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
  \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
  \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
  \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
  \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
  \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
    \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}%
}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \raisebox{-2\height}{%
      \makebox[\paperwidth]{\GradeHeader}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{5th Grade}
\lipsum[1-4]
\clearpage
\renewcommand\Grade{6}
\section{6th Grade}
\lipsum[1-4]
\clearpage
\renewcommand\Grade{7}
\section{7th Grade}
\lipsum[1-4]
\clearpage
\renewcommand\Grade{8}
\section{8th Grade}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]
Adjust the settings for the `\raisebox` to get the desired position in your actual document.

Comment: I mean 5 or 6 numbers of each kind on one relevant page. There should be a vertical bars between these big numbers. It is even better to have gray or different colours for both the numbers and the bars.

Comment: @Thumbolt Your description is still confusing. Please add to your question an image (even hand-drawn) of the desired output.

Comment: I have drawn a photo to illustrate my point.

Comment: @Thumbolt Thanks. I've updated my answer. Let me know of that is what you had in mind.

Comment: Before the  question pages, there should be some pages introducing the competition. So how to delay the effect of the commands until the first page of question set?