# control of the markers at header

Tags: header-footer

I need a booklet that has separate sections for different intended groups which should have a marker at the header. [Gonzalo helps to give the following](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268823/booklet-with-sections-separate-markers/268903#268903), but the title page and the pages that contain introduction and table of content should not have these markers. Could you help to cancel the appearance of these markers on the beginning pages?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\Grade{5}
\newcommand\GradeHeader{%
  \fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont%
  {\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
  \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
  \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
  \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
  \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
  \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
    \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}%
}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \raisebox{-2\height}{%
      \makebox[\paperwidth]{\GradeHeader}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    {\scshape\Large XYZ College  \par}
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\Large for grade 5 to grade 8 \par}
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    {\huge\bfseries Math Shortlisted Problems Booklet\par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\Large\itshape John Birdwatch\par}
    \vfill
     \par
    Dr.~Mark \textsc{Brown}

    \vfill

% Bottom of the page
    {\large \today\par}
\end{titlepage}



\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction }
\lipsum[1-2]
\clearpage

\section{Problem Committee}
\lipsum[1-2]
\clearpage

\section{5th Grade}
\lipsum[1-4]
\clearpage
\renewcommand\Grade{6}
 \section{6th Grade}
\lipsum[1-4]
\clearpage
\renewcommand\Grade{7}
\section{7th Grade}
\lipsum[1-4]
\clearpage
\renewcommand\Grade{8}
\section{8th Grade}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know that there is a preview where you can check the final post?

Comment: You mention an answer by Gonzalo Medina (i assume), where can we find that?

Comment: Yes http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268823/booklet-with-sections-separate-markers/268903#268903

Comment: The command `\AddToShipOutPictureBG` does what it is told to do. If you use the command *After* the pages you don't want to add something to header, it will be alright.

Comment: In fact, I have used command \Grade{5} after the Introduction pages and table of content but number 55555 still appears at the header.

Comment: You have to use *`\AddToShipoutPictureBG`* later.

Comment: Oh, I understand it now. Cut the whole AddToShipoutPicutreBG and paste on the page where the markers should begin.

Comment: When I remove the A6paper geometry, the gap between the picture and the first line is too big. How to reduce this gap?

Comment: Isn't that a new qustion?

Comment: Yes, should I pose a new question in a new post?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use \AddToShipoutPictureBG when you need it, not right at the start.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\Grade{5}
\newcommand\GradeHeader{%
    \fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont%
    {\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
    \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
    \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
    \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
    \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
    \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}\,\Grade%
    \,{\color{gray!60}\vrule width 3pt}%
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    {\scshape\Large XYZ College  \par}
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\Large for grade 5 to grade 8 \par}
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    {\huge\bfseries Math Shortlisted Problems Booklet\par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\Large\itshape John Birdwatch\par}
    \vfill
    \par
    Dr.~Mark \textsc{Brown}

    \vfill

                                                         % Bottom of the page
    {\large \today\par}
\end{titlepage}



\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction }
\lipsum[1-2]
\clearpage

\section{Problem Committee}
\lipsum[1-2]
\clearpage

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtPageUpperLeft{%
        \raisebox{-2\height}{%
            \makebox[\paperwidth]{\GradeHeader}%
        }%
    }%
}
\section{5th Grade}
\lipsum[1-4]
\clearpage
\renewcommand\Grade{6}
\section{6th Grade}
\lipsum[1-4]
\clearpage
\renewcommand\Grade{7}
\section{7th Grade}
\lipsum[1-4]
\clearpage
\renewcommand\Grade{8}
\section{8th Grade}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```