# How can I exclude pages from this Boolean command?

Tags: conditionals, everypage

I was using the code from [Harish Kumar's excellent answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163961/reference-to-the-table-of-contents-page) to create a link t my table of contents.    However, I wanted to alter it so that the link did not appear on the first two pages.

I tried using the `\everypage` package to create a hook that would exclude the first two pages from the function, but I'm not sure how to nest the hook to fit with the \ifthenelse.  Every attempt I tried to somehow combine in a hook, in various combinations, resulted in a compile error.

Here is the code, which, once again, I lifted from the earlier-linked excellent answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{linktoc}
\setboolean{linktoc}{true}  %%% uncomment to show answers properly
%\setboolean{linktoc}{false}  %%% comment to show answers properly

\newcommand\AtPageUpperRight[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{-0.3\paperheight}){#1}%
 }}%
\newcommand\AtPageLowerRight[1]{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0.3\paperheight}){#1}%
 }}%

\ifthenelse{\boolean{linktoc}}%
{%
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
   \AtPageUpperRight{\put(-70,0){\hyperref[toc]{Go to TOC}}}
   \AtPageLowerRight{\put(-70,0){\hyperref[toc]{Go to TOC}}}
    }%
}%
{}%


\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents\label{toc}
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

(I'm relatively new to using conditionals, so I apologize if my title or question uses incorrect terminology— please tell me if it does so I can edit it and make my question clearer)

Comment: related, see this comment http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285538/control-of-the-markers-at-header#comment689507_285538

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could condition on the value of the `page` counter, as you're adding content at the time of shipout (when the `page` counter is correct):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{eso-pic,hyperref}

\newif\iflinktoc
\linktoctrue%%% uncomment to show answers properly
%\linktocfalse%%% comment to show answers properly

\newcommand\AtPageUpperRight[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
  \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{-0.3\paperheight}){#1}%
}}%
\newcommand\AtPageLowerRight[1]{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
  \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0.3\paperheight}){#1}%
}}%

\newcommand{\addlinktotoc}{\hyperref[toc]{Go to ToC}}
\iflinktoc
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \ifnum\value{page}<3\else
      \AtPageUpperRight{\put(-70,0){\addlinktotoc}}%
      \AtPageLowerRight{\put(-70,0){\addlinktotoc}}%
    \fi
  }%
\fi

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents\label{toc}
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

I've dropped the use of [`ifthen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen), based on [Why is the `ifthen` package obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866/5764) and [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26200/5764).

Comment: Thank you! Good to know about `ifthen` — I had no idea it was obsolete